# How to retrieve and display a Contacts Address Label

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7, contacts

I am trying to retrieve postal addresses and their associated labels ( home, work etc.) from a CNContactsStore using the following code.
if let label = addressLabel {

```
            let addresses = contact.postalAddresses
            var addArray = [String]()
            let formatter = CNPostalAddressFormatter()

            for address in addresses {
                let addr = address.value as! CNPostalAddress
                let addLabel = address.label
                let formattedAddress = formatter.stringFromPostalAddress(addr)
                addArray.append(formattedAddress)

                print (addLabel)
                print(formattedAddress)
            }
            //print(addArray)
            label.text = addArray[0]
        }
```

The code works properly however the addLabel prints out the word "Home" bracketed by *$!<    >!$*  as opposed to just "Home".

Any idea what causes this and how to correct? addLabel is currently of type String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let addLabel = CNLabeledValue.localizedStringForLabel(address.label)
```